# Why differently shaped "IndexError"s when trying to access a list in a non-existing index in the same logical way differently while debbuging?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, index-error

I have stumbled upon a weird (to me) thing when debugging some bug I still have not understood.

When I access a list in two logically similar, but code-wise different ways, in an index that is out of range, I get two slightly different errors in the Evaluation window in pycharm.

Looks like this:

**definition**:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

**then**:

1)

```
a[111]
```

Result:

```
{IndexError}list index out of range
```

2. 

```
t = 111
a[t]
```

Result:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I add the list definition right before each access, the error looks the same, as the second version.

Does it have any significance? What can be understood from this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the version of python? I'm using python 3.10 and these gives me exactly same error

Comment: I work with python 3.8

Comment: @RowMow an array index of `111`, definitely raises an `IndexError` because your array does not have size >=112! Are you trying to access array elements, with binary index? `a[0b10]` would be the last statement to return you something. To @Fed_Dragon, too: python version is not the issue here.

Comment: @ Yannis P. 
Thanks. Fed_Dragon understood the question very well though. What I have asked is not about "why error?", but "why a different error?".